# Selecting an element having a colon in ID atribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have an identifier `id=cu:w` with a colon in it, how could I select it with jQuery?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cu:w').on('change', function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Check Here
    <input id='cu:w' type="checkbox">
  </legend>
  <span class="myClass">
            <p>This is the text.</p>
        </span>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double escape the colon

```
$('#cu\\:w')
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cEAnM/229/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `:` using `\\`:

```
$('#cu\\:w')
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cEAnM/228/)